IBM Speech To Text recognizeMicrophone Issues
I've been trying to use the recognizeMicrophone service to provide live transcriptions, but so far I've been unable to get it to work. I've done all the necessary setup, such as setting my credentials, but as soon as I call the recognizeMicrophone function by pressing a "Start Recording" button in my HTML, I get the error:
stream err WebSocket connection error: WebSocket connection error
    at socket.onerror (/Users/me/electron_tts_app/node_modules/.pnpm/watson-speech@0.41.0/node_modules/watson-speech/speech-to-text/recognize-stream.js:216:15)

I'm actually running this in an electron app, and this is my preload.js file:

require('dotenv').config()

const fs = require('node:fs')
const { IamAuthenticator, IamTokenManager } = require('ibm-watson/auth');
const SpeechToTextV1 = require('ibm-watson/speech-to-text/v1');
const recognizeMicrophone = require('watson-speech/speech-to-text/recognize-microphone');
const {contextBridge} = require('electron');

console.log('running')

const getIBMWatsonClientToken = (() => {
    const tokenManager = new IamTokenManager({
        apikey: process.env.SPEECH_TO_TEXT_IAM_APIKEY
    });

    let cachedToken = null

    return async () => {
        if (cachedToken)
            return cachedToken
        cachedToken = await tokenManager.getToken()
        console.log('got token as', cachedToken)
        fs.appendFile('logs.txt', `Got token: ${JSON.stringify(cachedToken)}\n`, function() {
            console.log('arguments', arguments)
        })
        return cachedToken
    }
})()

const setup = () => {
    document.getElementById('start').onclick = async function () {
        const stream = recognizeMicrophone({
            accessToken: await getIBMWatsonClientToken(), // You need to generate a token from your API key
            token: await getIBMWatsonClientToken(), // You need to generate a token from your API key
            objectMode: true, // enables object mode to receive objects instead of strings
            extractResults: true, // simplifies the response
            format: false // prevents formatting on the client side
            // model
        });

        stream.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log('stream data', data)
            document.getElementById('transcript').value += data.alternatives[0].transcript + '\n';
        });

        stream.on('error', function(err) {
            console.error('stream err', err);
        });

        document.getElementById('stop').onclick = function() {
            stream.stop();
        };
    };
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    sayHello: () => console.log('hello world'),
    setup,
    trySpeechToText: () => {
        const speechToText = new SpeechToTextV1({
            authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({ apikey: process.env.SPEECH_TO_TEXT_IAM_APIKEY }),
            serviceUrl: process.env.SPEECH_TO_TEXT_URL
        });
        speechToText.recognize({
            audio: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/../test-recording.m4a'),
            contentType: 'audio/mp4',
        })
        .then(r => {
            console.log('speech2txt response', r)
        })
    }
})


You might notice there's also a trySpeechToText function exposed to the frontend. When I try that, I see this error in the console:

Inspecting the network console for, I see that this is the full response for the trySpeechToText call:
{
   "error": "Stream was 15 bytes but needs to be at least 100 bytes.",
   "code": 400,
   "code_description": "Bad Request"
}

What could be causing both the recognizeMicrophone and speechToText modules to fail?
